# foundation 6 abide validation textarea unicode

Tags: unicode, zurb-foundation-6, abide

Is it possible to validate unicode text input with Foundation6 Abide? I am already using the following custom pattern

```
Foundation.Abide.defaults.patterns['alpha_numeric_spaces'] = /^[\w\-\s]+$/;
```

Comment: After seaching I modyfied the patern to: ^[\w\-\s-\u0000-\u007F\u0370-\u03FF\u0400-\u04FF\u0500-\u052F\u0530-\u058F]+$ and appears that is working at least for the languages that I am interestedin. The source for the unicode regex has been http://kourge.net/projects/regexp-unicode-block

Answer (score 0):

After seaching I modyfied the patern to: 
    Foundation.Abide.defaults.patterns['alpha_numeric_spaces'] = ^[\w-\s-\u0000-\u007F\u0370-\u03FF\u0400-\u04FF\u0500-\u052F\u0530-\u058F]+$;

and appears that is working at least for the languages that I am interestedin. The source for the unicode regex has been http://kourge.net/projects/regexp-unicode-block